# Kubernetes Stateful Set: Unable to attach or mount volume for more than one replica

Tags: kubernetes, persistent-volumes, stateful, kubernetes-statefulset

I am having a simple StatefulSet deployed on K8S:

```
kind: StatefulSet
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  name: sftp
  labels:
    app: sftp
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: sftp
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: sftp
    spec:
      volumes:
        - name: sftp-storage
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: sftp-pvc
      containers:
        - name: sftp
          image: atmoz/sftp
          ports:
            - containerPort: 22
              protocol: TCP
          envFrom:
            - secretRef:
                name: secret
          env:
            - name: SFTP_USERS
              value: >-
                $(SFTP_USERNAME):$SFTP_PASSWORD)::$(SFTP_GID):$(SFTP_ROOT_DIRECTORY)
          resources:
            limits:
              cpu: 500m
              memory: 128Mi
            requests:
              cpu: 250m
              memory: 64Mi
          volumeMounts:
            - name: sftp-storage
              mountPath: /home/user1
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
      securityContext:
        fsGroup: 10001
```

And my storage volume declaration is using a PVC as follows:

```
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: sftp-pvc
  labels:
    app: sftp
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 10Gi
  volumeName: pv-shoot--kyma--c-5f908c9-5ae6d56b-6560-4b00-9018-b17582336930
  storageClassName: files
  volumeMode: Filesystem
```

I thought that a setup like that should work without any issues, so that there wouldn't be any errors having 2 replicas on Stateful Set accessing one source on Persistant volume, but I am getting following messages on one of replica instances:

```
MountVolume.WaitForAttach failed for volume "pv-shoot--kyma--c-5f908c9-5ae6d56b-6560-4b00-9018-b17582336930" : volume attachment is being deleted
```

That is because the other instance is already attached to this volume.

What am I doing wrong here, can anyone help?

I think that it should be possible that multiple replica instances of the same Deployment or Stateful Set could access the same volume, or am I mistaken?

Comment: Thank you for your question. Questions focused specifically on Kubernetes, such as configuring or deploying a cluster, may be better answered by the experts in either the [sf] or [DevOps](https://devops.stackexchange.com/). These platforms are highly knowledgeable in Kubernetes and can provide comprehensive support tailored to your needs. As a reminder, all questions on Stack Overflow must be specifically related to programming. We appreciate your understanding and encourage you to visit the "on-topic" pages of either site before posting there to ensure a more relevant and helpful response.

Comment: Btw: I recommend reading what `accessModes: - ReadWriteOnce` means. It is not necessarily wrong in this context, but at least surprising.

Comment: Ok, I wasn't aware of the other sites dedicated to such topics.
What ReadWriteOnce means: "the volume can be mounted as read-write by a single node. ReadWriteOnce access mode still can allow multiple pods to access the volume when the pods are running on the same node. For single pod access, please see ReadWriteOncePod."
Which means that my deployment should work properly.

Comment: It is normally recommended to use a **volume claim template** with a **statefulset**, it will create a new **PVC** for each replica(i.e.Data is not going to be shared).Refer to this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72250853/what-happens-when-we-create-stateful-set-with-many-replicas-with-one-pvc-in-kube) by David Maze.

Comment: @KapilSakhare but doesn't that mean I'm going to have two instances with different files since there are physically different PVCs?

Comment: To prevent the error message you are getting. Try this **ReadWriteOncePod** access mode ensures that only one pod can mount the volume at a time, even if the pods are running on the same node.                         

To use the `ReadWriteOncePod` access mode, you can add the following annotation to your Stateful Set:

[volume.beta.kubernetes.io/storage-mode:](http://volume.beta.kubernetes.io/storage-mode:) **ReadWriteOncePod**

for more details refer this [blog](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2023/04/20/read-write-once-pod-access-mode-beta/#what-is-readwriteoncepod).

Answer (score 0):

You're doing it completely the read `accessModes` which you're using allows only one pod to be attached. you cannot attach not more than one pod.
the correct `accessModes` you should be using is `ReadWriteMany` - the volume can be mounted as read-write by many nodes.

Create a new `PersistentVolumeClaim` with `ReadWriteMany` as `accessModes`.

Also since the service you're deploying is `sftp`. by its nature if you want to run more replicas and should have a same storage attached to meaning you need to have an underlying `NAS` storage which can be shared across multiple deployments.

- you need a NAS/efs like storage attached to nodes.
- create a appropriate `storageclass`.
- create `pvc` with `ReadWriteMany`
- attach it to your pod.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however I don't think that ReadWriteMany access mode would help, for two reasons actually that is, firstly already tried it and the result is the same and secondly, based from Kubernetes' own documentation: "ReadWriteOnce: the volume can be mounted as read-write by a single node. ReadWriteOnce access mode still can allow multiple pods to access the volume when the pods are running on the same node. For single pod access, please see ReadWriteOncePod." So what I did should be correct. I want it on one node and this configuration should support mount of multiple pods.